# knockout foreach css multiple classes $data

Tags: css, knockout.js

In this example I have two additional css classes I want to add to a DIV.

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: [{name: 'Hello', size:'Triple'}]">
      <div class="tile"
       data-bind="css: {'tile-selected': true, $data.size : true}">
      </div>
    </div>
```

The first being 'tile-selected' based on a boolean. This works well.

The second is actually a name of a class 'Triple', (and in this example, always add it, ie 'True')

I get the error:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .;
>   Bindings value: css: {'tile-selected': true, $data.size : true}

I'm assuming that I can't use the $data.size part to pull in the 'Triple' literal from the 'size' property. Is there a way that I can do this? ($data['size'] also didn't seem to work)

Comment: What is the type of $data.size ? Is it an observable?

Comment: isn't $data the current iteration of the foreach?

Comment: Yes it is, I was asking about size.

Comment: size is a property of the hard coded array in the first div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the ko observables or properties as class names. Instead you would have to create a separate property for this and use the same for dynamic css binding something like below.

```
<div data-bind="css: sizeCSS">   Profit Information</div> 

var viewModel = {
/// some view model properties here.
        };

viewModel.sizeCSS = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.size();
}, viewModel);
```

EDIT: Check the dynamic CSS binding example here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Comment: Something i discovered is that it is not strictly true that you can't have properties as css class names. You can when using them in templates...

Comment: @RonWeston Is that with the css binding or the class binding? If it is with the css binding, can you share a sample?